# How is the "apt" command different from "apt-get" and "aptitude"?

Tags: software-installation, apt, package-management, aptitude

I just found out that there is a third command for installing packages available on my *Debian GNU/linux* distribution.

I found that I can install packages by simply entering:

```
apt install sl
            ^ package name
```

I prefer to use this command rather than `apt-get` or `aptitude` because it is easier to type and seems to do exactly the same thing.

But there might be some quirks with this that I am not aware of. Therefore I am wondering how `apt` is different from `apt-get` and `aptitude`.

**Note** that I am not asking for differences between `apt-get` and `aptitude`. There is already a question for that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767/what-is-the-real-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude-how-about-wajig).

I am asking how the `apt` command is different from `apt-get` and `aptitude` which the other question does not cover.

Comment: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155733/4671 This might not be an exact dupe, but it's close.

Comment: @Faheem It is close but I do not consider it at dupe. That question is very specific. It asks what `apt install` does while this question is much more general.

Answer (score 2):

The `apt` command is a more recent addition to the [apt package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt)

```
   Date: Tue, 01 Apr 2014 17:04:42 +0000 
   .....
   [ Michael Vogt ]
   * install apt binary
   * add apt.8.xml manpage
   * make fancy-progress fg/bg color configurable via something like
     Dpkg::Progress-Fancy::Progress-{bg,fg}="%1b[30m"
     (thanks to Tim Wasser for the suggestion)
   * Add progressbar to "Dpkg::Progress-Fancy"
   * fix documentation for APT::Periodic::MaxSize "0" (closes: #740551)
   * Use mkstemp() in apt-extracttemplaes (closes: #741627)
   * Add new Debug::RunScripts debug option
   * do not crash on SIGPIPE in pkgDPkgPM::RunScriptsWithPkgs()
   * enable DPkg::Progress-Fancy by default when "apt" is used
   * refresh po/pot and unfuzzy apt-extracttemplate manpage change
   * remove no longer needed apt.7 page
   * install "apt" binary by default
   * add sun-java{5,6}-jdk to breaks/replaces as they provided a
     "apt" binary as well
```

<sup>[Source](https://tracker.debian.org/news/54890)</sup>

As far as I can tell from [the blog](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/) of the person who did it, it basically combines the functionality of various apt commands:

> APT 1.0 was released on the 1. April 2014
>   [[0]](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/04/msg00013.html)!
>   The first APT version was announced on the 1. April exactly 16 years
>   ago
>   [[1]](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/1998/04/msg00027.html).
>
> The big news for this version is that we included a new “apt” binary
>   that combines the most commonly used commands from apt-get and
>   apt-cache. The commands are the same as their apt-get/apt-cache
>   counterparts but with slightly different configuration options.

`apt-get` etc are lower level, and are used as backends for some things (mainly install scripts), and according to the manual using `apt-get` in scripts etc is preferable. if you want. I suppose this update is to make things simpler and make apt more like other package managers.

Comment: Well, part of the reason is to discard historical baggage. For obvious reasons, the behavior of the `apt-cache` and `apt-get` commands can't be changed.

Comment: apt-get etc are lower level, and are used as backends for some things (probably including apt itself). I don't think that is true. The "probably including apt" bit is definitely untrue. What "some things" did you have in mind? Command line executables link directly to the apt library. And Python/Perl scripts use the apt Python/Perl bindings.